# Objective C UISegmentedControl Number Badges covered by hightlight color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, badge

I'd like to have number badges on my UISegements so I tried [MESegmentedControl](https://github.com/dave-thompson/MESegmentedControl) but the badges would appear at incorrect positions, (badge for index 0 would appear at index 1) not sure if due to autolayout or something else, so instead I 
added [Custom Badge](https://github.com/ckteebe/CustomBadge) to each of my segments, it's working sweet except the hightlight color would sometimes cover the badge. I tried bringToFront but that didn't help. Is there anything I can call to fix that?  Thanks for your help!

[image: No mi gusta!]

My code creating the badges in viewWillAppear:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGFloat totalW = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    JSCustomBadge *badgeALL = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"1"];
    JSCustomBadge *badgeCA = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"2"];
    JSCustomBadge *badgeOR = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"3"];
    JSCustomBadge *badgeNV = [JSCustomBadge customBadgeWithString:@"4"];

    NSMutableArray *badges = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                          badgeALL, badgeKLN, badgeNT, badgeHK,nil];

    CGFloat y = 0.0f;
    CGFloat thisW = 23.0f;
    CGFloat thisH = 23.0f;

    badgeALL.frame = CGRectMake(totalW*0.15,  y, thisW,thisH);
    badgeCA.frame = CGRectMake(totalW*0.375, y, thisW,thisH);
    badgeOR.frame = CGRectMake(totalW*0.6,   y, thisW,thisH);
    badgeNV.frame = CGRectMake(totalW*0.83, y, thisW,thisH);

    for (JSCustomBadge *each in badges) {
        [_districtsSegCtrl  addSubview:each];
        [_districtsSegCtrl bringSubviewToFront:each];
   }
};
```